# Rails: code in model or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

What is the best approach here? I'm trying to clean up some code and I'm wondering if the controller is the best place for this variety of logic:

```
if user_signed_in?
  if current_user.try(:admin?)
    @docs = Doc.chronologic.page(params[:page]).per(5)
    @orders = Order.chronologic.page(params[:page]).per(5)
  else
    @docs = Doc.chronologic.where(:user_id => current_user.ftp, :retired => "active").page(params[:page]).per(5)
    @orders = Order.chronologic.where(:user => current_user.ftp).page(params[:page]).per(5)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @docs }
  end
else 
  redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
```

If there's a better location for it, where would it be?

Thanks!

**Edit:** it's far worse for methods like `pdf` which has line after line of instructions for Prawn, but I can't seem to get `send_data` to work from the model.

Comment: Which `if` bothers you? The `user_signed_in?` one or the `admin?` one?

Comment: I suppose you could have `for_user` scopes but that's a matter of opinion in a simple case like this. The `user_signed_in?` really should be handled by a `before_filter` though. And there's no need to `current_user.try(:admin?)`, just `current_user.admin?` should be sufficient since the `user_signed_in?` check should avoid the `current_user.nil?` case and you're assuming `!current_user.nil?` for non-admin users anyway.

Comment: Side note: Ryan Bates did [an excellent RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn-revised) which shows a good way to generate PDFs with Prawn, and keeps the code out of your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically what mu said, but here's my take.

In your app controller:

```
def require_logged_in
  redirect_to new_user_session_path unless user_signed_in?
end
```

In your controller

```
before_filter :require_logged_in

def some_action
  @docs = Doc.chronologic.for_user(current_user).page(params[:page]).per(5)
  @orders = Order.chronologic.for_user(current_user).page(params[:page]).per(5)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @docs }
  end
end
```

In your Doc model

```
scope :for_user, lambda do |user|
  where(:user_id => user.ftp, :retired => "active") unless user.admin?
end
```

And something similar in your Order model.

Per your edit, definitely don't do `send_data` from your model.

Comment: That's a great solution. Cheers!